# How to write a jest unit-test using the gatsby.navigate function?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, gatsby, react-testing-library

Evening all,

I am building a client side only app with Gatsby.

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my `<Login />` component.

Once a user has successfully logged in, they are redirected to /app/,
programatically via gatsby's navigate function

This is my test thus far:

```
import React from 'react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import 'jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { navigate } from 'gatsby'
import {
    render,
    fireEvent,
    cleanup,
    act,
    wait
} from '~/__tests__/utils/wrapper'
import Login from '../index'

describe('<Login />', () => {

    afterEach(cleanup)

    it('should redirect to /app/ when the correct details are used', async () => {
        const { getByTestId, getByLabelText } = render(<Login />)
        const emailField = getByLabelText('Email address')
        const passwordField = getByTestId('password-input')

        act(() => {
            userEvent.type(emailField, 'test@email.com')
            userEvent.type(passwordField, 'password')
        })

        await wait()

        act(() => {
            fireEvent.click(getByTestId('login-submit'))
        })

        await wait()

        expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // FAILS
        expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/app/') // FAILS
    })
})
```

I have followed the docs here: 
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/unit-testing/#3-useful-mocks-to-complete-your-testing-environment

I've also added `navigate: jest.fn()` to the exported object.

The component is working so it's definitely something to do with my test.

Any help, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation here:

https://testing-library.com/docs/example-reach-router

I've now wrapped the component like so

```
function renderWithRouter(
    ui,
    { route = '/', history = createHistory(createMemorySource(route)) } = {}
) {
    return {
        ...render(<LocationProvider history={history}>{ui}</LocationProvider>),
        // adding `history` to the returned utilities to allow us
        // to reference it in our tests (just try to avoid using
        // this to test implementation details).
        history
    }
}
```

Also...

[https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-link/src/**tests**/index.js](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-link/src/__tests__/index.js)

for further ideas

Answer (score 0):

In the root of your project (outside /src), you should add `__mocks__/gatsby.js`.

You can mock gatsby functions here, including `navigate`.

An example:

```js
// __mocks__/gatsby.js
const gatsby = jest.requireActual('gatsby');

module.exports = {
  ...gatsby,
  navigate: jest.fn(),
}
```

In your test you will need to tell jest to use this mock with `jest.mock('gatsby');`.

---

Alternatively, you can mock in your test file:

```js
// __tests__/Component.jsx
jest.mock('gatsby', () => {
  const gatsby = jest.requireActual('gatsby');

  return {
    ...gatsby,
    navigate: jest.fn(),
  }
});
```